# no such column: chat_conversation.created_date

Tags: python, django

I am trying to view a Conversation model I created in Python 3.7 with Django.  I am new to Python, Django, and making webapps.  I have done the makemigrations and migrate commands, but I still get the "no such column: chat_conversation.created_date" error:

[image: Local webapp error]

[Output from running migrations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoPKk.png)

Here is the model.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import uuid

class Conversation(models.Model):#keeps track of conversation id
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

This is what I have for the views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Conversation
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def con_list(request):
    con = Conversation.objects.filter(created_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('created_date')
    return render(request, 'chat/con_list.html', {'con': con})

def con_new(request, pk):
    if request.method == "CONVERSATION":
        #form = ConversationForm(request.CONVERSATION)
        if form.is_valid():
            #conversation = form.save(commit=False)
            conversation.created_date = timezone.now()
            conversation.save()
            return redirect('con_list')
    #else:
        #form = ConversationForm()
    return render(request, 'chat/post_list.html' )#{'form': form})

def con_edit(request, pk):
    conversation = get_object_or_404(Conversation, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "CONVERSATION":
        #form = ConversationForm(request.CONVERSATION, instance=conversation)
        if form.is_valid():
            #conversation = form.save(commit=False)
            conversation.created_date = timezone.now()
            conversation.save()
            return redirect('con_list')
    #else:
        #form = ConversationForm(instance=conversation)
    return render(request, 'chat/con_edit.html' )#{'form': form})
```

I have commented some parts out that I would like to add back, but after i get the basics working. Here is the url.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('conversations', views.con_list, name='con_list'),
    path('conversation/new/', views.con_new, name='con_new'),
    path('conversation/<int:pk>/edit/', views.con_edit, name='con_edit'),
]
```

And finally this is my con_list.html

```
{% extends 'chat/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% for conversation in con %}
        <div class="conversation">
            <p><b>{{ conversation.id }}</b> <b>&middot;</b> <i>{{ 
                 conversations.created_date }}</i> <br/></p>
            <a href="{% url 'con_new' %}" >
                <button type="submit" style="background-color:rgb(255, 148, 26); border-radius: 10px">
                <font color="white"><b>New Chat Room</b></font>
                </button>
            </a>
            <a href="{% url 'post_list' %}" >
                <button type="submit" style="background-color:rgb(255, 148, 26); border-radius: 10px">
                <font color="white"><b>{{ conversation.id }}</b></font>
                </button>
            </a>
        <br/><br/><br/>
        <hr style="border-color:orange;" />
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        Click the button below to logout
        <p><a href="{% url 'logout' %}">logout</a></p>
        {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Can you show your Chat model?

Comment: chat is the name of the app, so I don't have a model for it.

Comment: Did you add the field `created_date` after another migration?

Comment: I've migrated several times.  At one point I had a conversation title, then replaced it with the ID.  But, I think that created_date was one of the first objects I put in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you change the name of your `user` table.

Go to the `migrations` directory within your 'chat' app and in the file: `0005....py` add `atomic = False`. You should be able to rename your table and finally migrate.

Comment: Well that fixed the error thank you!  Now I just need to figure out why my buttons aren't showing up haha.